# Configuring knex database connection uisng an access key

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Well I recently started using knex for my database connectivity for my nodejs project. Here's the following code:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        'host':'localhost',
        'port':'3306',
        'user':'root',
        'password':'',
        'database':'db_sample'
    }
});
```

So what I need is, I want to add an access key as well in my Database configuration. I just wanted to know if its possible to do it. If yes, please do tell me how. Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by access key here? Please explain on the question

Comment: By access key I meant a particular token for that database if we give wrong token the database won't connect. I kinda configured that using if else but I'm just looking for another alternative to see if its possible

Comment: Is this possible without Knex? I mean if we connect with mysql without using Knex

Comment: I think you can do this on the PHP end, rather than using specific mysql configuration.

Comment: well, I know its possible with mysql I've done it too. But I couldn't able to find how to configure in knex. I'm just searching for an alternative. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: If you can tell how that is done generally with `mysql` I can tell you if it can be done with `knex + mysql`.